# Upload PDF with OCR with google apps script (and possibly drive API)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, ocr

I'm using Google Apps script to upload a pdf from the web, but I'd like to upload it while automatically performing OCR. So far, I can upload it, but I don't know how to perform OCR on it.

```
  var link = "http://ilwu13.com/dispatches/" ;
  var date_str = "011813" ; //My code creates this based on today's date
  var link_end = "_DF.pdf" ;

  link = link + date_str + linkend ;


  var urlfetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link) ;
  var fileBlob = urlfetch.getBlob();
  var new_gdoc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob) ;
```

I understand this question was already answered in this post, https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#uploading_documents_using_optical_character_recognition_ocr, but the "Google Documents List API has been officially deprecated" after it was posted.

The deprecated DocsList API will work until 2015, but I'd like a more stable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with the Drive API. See the [`drive.files.insert`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) method with special attention to the `ocr` and `ocrLanguage` parameters.

Comment: any reason why ocrLanguage not supporting hebrew "iw"

Comment: @user1469051 - Explicit code available in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613809/getting-certain-pdf-attachments-from-my-gmail-as-text/26623198#26623198).